# Issue with a one page website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating my first one page website and it's not quite working right. This is what I have currently: http://jsfiddle.net/wfjgq7xq/

Firstly, when I click a link i.e. test 3, test 2 highlights to say it's on that page, I then have to scroll the page a little to highlight the test 3.

Secondly, there is a delayed reaction to the highlights, when scrolling through the page, the highlights should change when each page it being scrolled through, this is delayed and it doesn't change for a couple of seconds by then i'm at the bottom of the page.

Thirdly, the start of the page is always under the header, I need to move this down but top:60; didn't work

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {      
$('.scroll').click(function(){
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('body').stop().scrollTo( $target , 800, {'axis':'y'});
    return false;
});
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('div[id^="test"]').each(function(i){
        if($(this).position().top < scrollPosition) {
         $('nav li').removeClass('active');
            $('nav li:eq('+i+')').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
});
```

UPDATE: the delay seems to be a Safari thing!

Comment: I don't see the delay in highlighting that you mention. What browser are you using? Mine is Firefox 31.0.

Comment: latest safari on the mac, i'll try firefox now and let you know

Comment: there is no delat on chrome too, on windows

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester OK so the delay must be a Safari thing as it's ok in firefox and chrome on the mac, but there is still the issue with clicking the links with them, then the bug with Safari needs looking at

Comment: No delays in chrome or IE, so it might be a safari issue on it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the offset from the header. The scroll does not take into account the header's position as it is fixed down there.

```
var offsetHeader = 60;

$('.scroll').click(function(){
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('body').stop().scrollTo( $target , 800, {'axis':'y', offset: -offsetHeader});
    return false;
});
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('div[id^="test"]').each(function(i){
        console.log(1, $(this).position().top);
        console.log(2, scrollPosition);
        if($(this).position().top <= scrollPosition + offsetHeader) {
            $('nav li').removeClass('active');
            $('nav li:eq('+i+')').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Basically you can tell the jquery scrollto plugin to offset the scroll. Also for the navigation link, you would also need to include the offset when doing the comparison.

To add the offset from the header at the start of your page, you can add a invisible container with a height:

In CSS add this:

```
div#offsetBlock
{
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
}
```

In HTML add this right after the header and before the first container which is test1

```
<div id="offsetBlock">
</div>
```

Note: you might not be able to scroll until test6 properly because the scroll has already reached the end of the page.

Comment: Hi I marked it as answered but then realised that the first div is behind the header? apart from that it worked ok.

Comment: Yep i forgot about the first part, i edited my answer. The end of the page can be adjusted by adding more spaces into the last container. Do note that different screen sizes affects the scroll as well.